# How to provide security to the code in php desktop

Tags: php, mongoose-web-server, phpdesktop

I want to provide an security to the code present in Mongoose server Which is used for making desktop.

I want to deliver the desktop application to the client but the client is able to read the code under www folder in Mongoose server, That was not encrypt like java like class file.

Just like anybody can stole the data from the folder, That's why how should i Provide security to that folder.

Comment: Java class files aren't "encrypted"… but anyway, it sounds like you want an obfuscation tool. Search the web. (Though if you're worried about your client "stealing" your code I think you've got bigger problems…)

Answer (score 1):

From phpdesktop website:

> PHP sources can be protected with the many of the available PHP
>   encoders.

https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Knowledge-Base#how-do-i-protect-php-sources-in-the-www-directory